# Bartender Challange, Error ocde : challange3.rb:64:in `<main>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I was trying to solve this challange which is quite basic. Everything else works well until I start adding the total profit for the order and I receive the error : "challange3.rb:64:in `<main>': undefined method` +' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)".

Challenge 3: Bartender challenge

You are working at a bar where you have a current backlog of drinks to make:

3 cocktails,
2 waters and
6 beers
write a program that asks the customer for their order.

if they order a cocktail, add one to the number of cocktails you need to make.
if they order a water, add one to the number of waters you need to make.
if they order a beer, add one to the number of beers you need to pour.
print the final drinks order so you know what to make.
cocktails sell for $22, and cost $8 to make.
beer sell for $12, and cost $3 to pour.
water sell for $6, and cost $0.15 to make.
print out the total profit for the orders you have.

Here is my code

```
backlog_cocktails = 3
backlog_waters = 2
backlog_beers = 6

cocktail_cost = 8
water_cost = 0.15
beer_cost = 3

cocktail_selling_price = 22
water_selling_price = 6
beer_selling_price = 12

total_profit = " "
p "Are you ordering?"
are_you_ordering  = gets.chomp      

while are_you_ordering == "yes" 
    puts "We have Cocktails, Waters and beers for order."
    puts "What orders do you want to make?"
    customer_order = gets.chomp

    if customer_order == "cocktail"
        backlog_cocktails += 1 
        cocktail_profit = (cocktail_selling_price - cocktail_cost) * backlog_cocktails
    

    elsif customer_order == "water"
        backlog_waters += 1
        water_profit = (water_selling_price - water_cost) * backlog_waters
        
        

    else customer_order == "beer"
         backlog_beers += 1
        beer_profit = (beer_selling_price - beer_cost) * backlog_beers
    
    end
    p "We got cocktail: #{backlog_cocktails}, water: #{backlog_waters} and beer: #{backlog_beers} to make."
    puts "Do you want to make more order?"

    are_you_ordering = gets.chomp 
    
    total_ profit = cocktail_profit + water_profit + beer_profit
    p total_profit
    
end
```

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is occurring because you are trying to add to a variable that is currently `nil` when you are calculating `total_profit`.  To fix this error, initialize `cocktail_profit`, `water_profit`, and `beer_profit` to 0 before your `while` loop.

```
cocktail_profit = 0.0
water_profit = 0.0
beer_profit = 0.0

while are_you_ordering == "yes" 
    ...
```

Comment: I tried it and yet got this error: challange3.rb:68:in `<main>': undefined method `total_' for main:Object (NoMethodError).

Comment: You have a space between `total_` and `profit`.  Removing the space should fix that error

Comment: Thanks so much. Seems like its working now. I am novice to the coding. I dont know how I can i improve myself?

Comment: @Niraj I recommend that you [click the grey checkmark next to this post so it turns green](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).